# What does it mean for T-biconditionals to be derivable unrestrictedly?

Tags: truth

I have been reading Leitgeb's *What Theories of Truth Should be Like*, and one of the desiderata for a theory of truth, he argues, is to have unrestricted derivable T-biconditionals. But I am having trouble understanding what he meant exactly by the T-biconditional.

What he described seems to be the equivalent of Tarski's material adequacy, because he explicitly mentioned:

> For example, if ‘Tr(‘snow is white’) if and only if snow is white’
> were not derivable, then an important aspect of our understanding ‘Tr’
> as being applied to the sentence ‘snow is white’ would not be
> reflected by this definition. At best the definition would specify the
> actual meaning of ‘Tr’ incompletely, in the worst case it might assign
> the wrong extension to ‘Tr’.

And this seems to corresponds to Tarski's motivation for the material adequacy condition. In other words, when he is talking about ‘Tr(‘snow is white’) if and only if snow is white’, this appears to be the Convention-T which is the formalised version of material adequacy, not T-schema which is an inductive definition of truth.

However, in a latter part where he describes the unrestricted derivability of T-biconditionals he talks about the T-scheme, which I take it to be the T-schema:

> The same seems to hold for all other sentences of the form ‘Tr(‘A’) if
> and only if A’ where ‘A’ is replaced by a sentence of the very
> language that we are interested in. Indeed, the derivability of all
> instances of the T-scheme from a definition of truth guarantees that
> the latter assigns the ‘right’ extension to ‘Tr’, which at least seems
> to be a necessary condition for what a ‘good’ definition of truth must
> be like.

This seems to suggest that when Leitgeb is talking about the T-biconditional, he doesn't have Convention-T - the condition that Tarski argues all theories of truth should comply - in mind; instead he seems to have the T-schema in mind.

But this doesn't seem to make sense. Leitgeb is not trying to come up with a theory of truth in this paper, but a desiderata for a theory of truth. The T-schema is Tarski's theory of truth which satisfies the material adequacy condition. If by the T-biconditional Leitgeb meant the T-schema, not Convention-T, this means he is arguing that all theories of truth must have a unrestricted provable T-schema - which is equivalent to saying that the T-schema is a presumed desiderata for all theories of truth, and obviously that is circular.

For example, intuitionistic logic conforms with Convention-T, but does not comply with T-schema since it is not truth-functional, which is a key characteristic of T-schema. Therefore what Leitgeb suggested would have excluded all theories of truth that are non-classical based)

Could anyone help me interpret what exactly does Leitgeb mean by the T-biconditional please?

PS: This question has some overlaps with my previous question about the distinction between the T-schema and Convention-T, but I feel like this is not quite the same question.
[Is T-schema just another name for Convention-T, or are they two different things?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81703/is-t-schema-just-another-name-for-convention-t-or-are-they-two-different-things)

---

The relevant excerpt is as follows:

> Sentences of the form ‘Tr(‘A’) if and only if A’, in which the
> schematic letter ‘A’ is replaced by a declarative sentence of a given
> language, are called T-biconditionals for this language (‘T’ for
> truth,‘biconditional’ because of the ‘if and only if ’); ‘Tr(‘A’) if
> and only if A’ itself is called the T-scheme. The famous ‘Tr(‘snow is
> white’) if and only if snow is white’ is the paradigm case example of
> a T-biconditional.
>
> Tarski was the first to notice the methodological importance of the
> T-scheme: his idea was to define truth, i.e. to state a definition of
> the form ‘Tr(x) if and only if . . .’, and then to test the semantic
> adequacy of this definition by checking whether all T-biconditionals
> for the language for which truth is to be defined are derivable from
> it. If not, the definition is deficient. For example, if ‘Tr(‘snow is
> white’) if and only if snow is white’ were not derivable, then an
> important aspect of our understanding ‘Tr’ as being applied to the
> sentence ‘snow is white’ would not be reflected by this definition. At
> best the definition would specify the actual meaning of ‘Tr’
> incompletely, in the worst case it might assign the wrong extension to
> ‘Tr’.
>
> The same seems to hold for all other sentences of the form ‘Tr(‘A’) if
> and only if A’ where ‘A’ is replaced by a sentence of the very
> language that we are interested in. Indeed, the derivability of all
> instances of the T-scheme from a definition of truth guarantees that
> the latter assigns the ‘right’ extension to ‘Tr’, which at least seems
> to be a necessary condition for what a ‘good’ definition of truth must
> be like.

Comment: From your above quote *‘Tr(‘A’) if and only if A’ itself is called the T-scheme*, so seems Leitgeb simply treats T-scheme same as convention-T.

Comment: @DoubleKnot But does Leitgeb's point make sense? Because if he equates the T-biconditional to T-scheme (and also Convention-T), and he is arguing that one of the desiderata should be having a unrestrictedly provable T-biconditional, then this desiderata is equivalent to having a unrestrictedly provable T-scheme. But this desiderata then essentially rules out any theory of truth that is non-classical logic based, the prime example being intuitionistic logic? Shouldn't a desiderata be neutral on this matter? It seems to me that this is somewhat circular

Comment: Leitgeb seems only talking about Convention-T's material adequacy only, not about any of those inductive truth functional definitions of classic bivalent logic specifically. So this doesn't rule out other non-classic logics. Similar to modal logic which is obviously non-truth-functional, intuitionistic logic has Kripke possible world relational semantics handling the non-truth-functional part, Heyting lattice algebraic semantics, Curry-Howard correspondence, etc. All these semantic theories satisfy Convention-T in their own ways albeit there's non-truth-functional satisfiability constraints...